# why is related_name plural for ForeignKey?

Tags: django-models

Currently I am reading

> Django 4 By Example - Fourth Edition

We are creating a `Post` model in `blog` app.
The table is named as `blog_post` as per the `sqlmigrate` commands.

But when we add a `ForeignKey`from `Post` to `User` model by

```
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                           related_name='blog_posts')
```

the `related_name` is `blog_posts` instead of `blog_post`.

Why is it in plural instead of the actual table name?

Answer (score 2):

The [**`related_name=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) is used to query items in reverse. In this case it means that for a given `User` (author), you can retrieve all the `Post`s that author has written with:

```
my_user.blog_posts.all()
```

Since there can be *zero*, *one*, or *more* such `Post`s, this is a collection, and hence it is usually written in plural form. `my_user.blog_post.all()` would hint that this is a single item, which is not the case.

If you do not specify a name, the default for `related_name=…` will be `modelname_set`, with *`modelname`* the name of the model in lowercase, so `post_set`, again to hint that this is a *collection* of `Post` objects.

For a [**`OneToOneField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField) the `related_name=…` is usually *singular*, since then there would only be *at most* one such `Post`. The default for the `related_name=…` for a `OneToOneField` is therefore *`modelname`*, so here it would be `post`.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).